# React-hook-form, and dndkit. Take onChange input and update image component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

Using react-hook-form, and dndkit. I want to take the onChange input of a url input, and run it through a function that finds the image that corresponds to that url. I also want the image to use the fields default value when first loading in from the database. Right now it only for some reason works when I remount the component (submit or move the link component around. Heres my code:

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        links: links.map((link) => ({
            id: link.id,
            title: link.title,
            url: link.url,
            image: link.image || undefined,
        })),
    },
})
const onLinkInputChange = (e: any, index: number) => {
    const url = e.target.value
    const new_url = url
        .replace('https://', '')
        .replace('http://', '')
        .split('/')[0]
    const site = sites.find(
        (site) =>
            new_url.includes(site.domain) || site.domain.includes(new_url)
    )
    fields[index].image = site?.favicon || '/globe.svg'
    setValue(`links.${index}.image`, site?.favicon || '/globe.svg')
}
<DndContext onDragEnd={handleDragDrop}>
                <SortableContext
                    items={fields}
                    strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
                >
                    {fields.map((field, index) => (
                        <DraggableLink id={field.id} key={field.id}>
                            <div className="flex-col w-full">
                                <div className="flex-row flex justify-start h-full w-full">
                                    <div className="bg-neutral-900 w-full aspect-square max-w-[120px] relative rounded-lg p-2 md:p-4 flex items-center justify-center">
                                        <Image
                                            alt="Logo"
                                            fill
                                            key={field.image}
                                            sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 33vw"
                                            priority
                                            className="object-contain p-3"
                                            {...register(
                                                `links.${index}.image`
                                            )}
                                            src={
                                                field.image || '/globe.svg'
                                            }
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <FormField
                                            control={form.control}
                                            key={index}
                                            name={`links.${index}.url`}
                                            render={({ field }) => (
                                                <FormItem>
                                                    <FormControl>
                                                        <Input
                                                            placeholder="Link URL"
                                                            {...field}
                                                            {...register(
                                                                `links.${index}.url`,
                                                                {
                                                                    onChange:
                                                                        (
                                                                            e
                                                                        ) => {
                                                                            onLinkInputChange(
                                                                                e,
                                                                                index
                                                                            )
                                                                        },
                                                                }
                                                            )}
                                                        />
                                                    
                                                  </FormControl>
                                                    <FormMessage />
                                                </FormItem>
                                            )}
                                        />
```

My problem is that I want this to happen when I change the input, live. and stay with the link when I move it.